# Adaptive sorting algorithms versus sorting networks for sorting a list of 32 random elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, optimization, sorting-network

If we are using a sequential machine (parallel comparisons is not possible) where comparisons are made in sequence and and we are looking to minimize the number of processor clock cycles when sorting 32 random elements, should we use a sorting network or an adaptive sorting algorithm?

There are no optimal networks (yet) for n=32 elements. In practical terms, if we want to minimize the number of CPU clock cycles, is it best to divide 32 elements into four sublists of n=8 and apply the optimal sorting network on each sublist, then merge the lists together?

We are obviously working with "average performance" here, because adaptive algorithms can get lucky if we are given an already sorted list.

Crunching the numbers we have the following:

Sorting a list of size n:

- Minimum number of comparisons for n=2 is 1.
- Minimum number of comparisons for n=4 is 5.
- Minimum number of comparisons for n=8 is 19.

Merging two lists of size n:

- Merge two lists of n=2 is 2*n - 1 = 3 comparisons
- Merge two lists of n=4 is 2*n - 1 = 7 comparisons
- Merge two lists of n=8 is 2*n - 1 = 15 comparisons.
- Merge two lists of n=16 is 2*n - 1 = 31 comparisons.

Total number of comparisons if we divide n=32 into sixteen n=2 sublists:

- Sorting: 1*16 = 16
- Merge: 3*8 + 7*4 + 15*2 + 31*1 = 113
- Total: 129

Total number of comparisons if we divide n=32 into eight n=4 sublists:

- Sorting: 5*8 = 40
- Merge: 7*4 + 15*2 + 31*1 = 89
- Total: 129

Total number of comparisons if we divide n=32 into four n=8 sublists:

- Sorting: 19*4 = 76
- Merge: 15*2 + 31*1 = 61
- Total: 137

Now one might think it would be better to divide the n=32 elements into n=2 or n=4 sublists since the total number of comparisons is smaller. But mergin requires storing parts of the array "out-of-place" which might negate the benefit of less comparisons?

My gut feeling tells me that on average the non-adaptive sorting network is similar to an algorithm in terms of total comparisons but the sorting network wins due to less overhead, am I right?

---

I am trying to sort n=32 elements in less than 1200 clock cycles on average. I am working [on a simple sequential machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010435/shift-bit-8-15-to-bit-0-7-in-as-few-clock-cycles-as-possible-in-machine-code) with a simple **256 words * 16bit memory and only four registers**, so the network/algorithm has to be simple, fast and not require a lot of space. The ALU only has adding, subtracting, one bit shift, one bit rotating, AND, and OR functionality.   Memory and ALU operations take a single clock cycle each.

Comment: Most of the sorting algorithms are n*log(n), i.e. 32*5 = 160. Except specialities like radix sort, but that depends what kind of values you are sorting (if you would want to sort values 0-15 and you can use count array with 16 elements, you can sort it in about ~90 instructions in total (16 to zero count array, 32 to count elements, 32 to output sorted array)). And are the elements truly random, or is there some weak spot in their "randomness" giving you chance to expect something about them? (on almost-sorted array some sorting algorithms will perform better than others) What will this do?

Comment: (sounds to me a bit like some kind of HW sprites thing or something similar, so there's maybe some ugly shortcut to implement this without full accurate sort)

Comment: As pointed out in comments, an optimum sorting network for 32 items would require about 160 comparisons. That means you'd have to average 7.5 cycles per comparison. I don't know what your machine's instruction timings are, but that seems quite ambitious. Load two operands from memory, subtract, compare, and branch, all in fewer than 7.5 cycles? Then multiply swapping time (two more memory accesses) by the average number of swaps necessary. Are you sure your problem is even solvable, given the constraints?

Comment: @JimMischel There is a competition every year at my university with this particular setup and last year the guy who won managed to sort five random n=32 lists with an average of 1157 clock cycles per list.

Comment: @JimMischel 
With my current solution I am down to 9 clock cycles per comparison excluding the swaps and 12 clock cycles including the swaps. This doesn't include the mergin part of the sublists, so I am not happy with this solution. 
Aki Suihkonen mentioned using Heap sort as a potential solution to the problem. Do you think Heap will outperform an optimal sorting network in this particular case?

Comment: @Ped7g I have been told that the lists are taken from "/dev/random" whatever that means, but I guess they are completely random. The elements in the list are in the range of 0000-FFFF hexadecimal. Would radix sort be near optimal in this case?

Comment: Yes, Linux `/dev/random` is a maximally-random stream of bytes, so for you that means uniformly-distributed 16-bit integers, with no bias towards already being partially sorted.  (Unlike many real-world sort inputs, but good for not biasing towards any particular sort algo).

Comment: I don't think you have enough memory or a fast enough ALU shifter to RadixSort efficiently.  You can rotate the high 1 or 2 bits around to the bottom and mask off the other bits, though.  Analyzing just number of comparisons is a totally flawed approach when you only have 4 registers; some algos are going to need a lot more spill/reload if they need to track more stuff.  *Please update on how your machine accesses memory*: Do you always need to load into a register before using, or do you have instructions that subtract a memory operand from the ALU register?  Like `sub reg,[mem]`?

Comment: Merging is cheap on compares, but usually requires copying both inputs somewhere else, which might be more machine cycles than something that sometimes doesn't swap after a compare.

Comment: Heap sort might be a good alternative. Be sure to read up on some of the optimizations that give very close to theoretic minimum number of comparisons. But try the straightforward implementation first.

Comment: `[min #]comparisons for n=8 is 19` if that is from [wikipedia on #comparisons required to sort a list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list), there's something off - it should be 16 for a grand total of 125.

Comment: no-so-wild guess: going down the "minimum comparison sort" way, you *will* run out of code space - think or the permutation you still have to perform once you have determined it. One of the most important questions about your machine: 1) availability of, say, *conditional move*s 2) time taken by a) *call/return* b) *conditional branches*.

Comment: no, 16bit /dev/random is not a good candidate for radix, but it is excellent candidate for guessing middle value as half of range (i.e. split value for 0-15,16-31 is very likely to be around 0x8000, then the next split on those halves are likely to be around 0x4000 and 0xC000 ... at least statistically, on many many samples. On mere 32 elements and only few runs it may not demonstrate such even distribution, linux random is reasonably strong.

Comment: @greybeard Where can I find the minimum network for n=8, do you have a link?

Comment: @PeterCordes I will try to do an update on my question with more details about the machine. For now I can say that the machine has a register which acts as a pointer to the memory. So if you want to store a value from a register to memory you have to first load the pointer value to the pointer register on first clock cycle and then for the second clock cycle you can send the desired value to memory. If you want to load a value from memory you first send the pointer value to the pointer register on the first clock cycle and then the second clock cycle you load to desired register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Important detail missing from above: If you want to use any of the four registers you have to send a pointer value to another register (this is called IR, while the pointer register for memory is called ASR) which then opens up the data transfer to the register you want.

Comment: @PeterCordes There is however two other registers I haven't mentioned that is called HR and AR, where the second one is used by the ALU for calculations. Since you have to use a pointer to use the main four registers (called gr0-gr3) I think it's faster to use HR, AR and the IR register since these do not require a pointer, you can send values to these "directly" either from memory or other registers. But as I said, memory always requires a pointer to be updated to load or store from a particular address.

Comment: Two sorting models to distinguish here: sorting on a general purpose computer (often designated [RAM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine)) vs. using a dedicated [sorting network](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Optimal_sorting_networks). I suppose that your machine (while *heavily* under-specified) is (_much_ closer to) a generic RAM. Confusingly(?), the minimum upper bound on the number of comparisons necessary to sort *n* value is higher for networks only from 5 up. "RAM style" would be advantageous with costly comparisons, network with conditional moves.

Comment: @greybeard I have posted a new question with more information about the computer model. Check it out.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have posted a new question with more information about the computer model. Check it out.

Comment: @Ped7g I have posted a new question with more information about the computer model. Check it out.

Comment: You might want to check this paper if you've not already done so: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01962.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Heap sort is nlogn. The index calculation is trivial -- the items to be compared have always indices of n, 2n+{1,2 } making it computationally efficient with your architecture.

The workhorse of the heap sort is basically the routine:

```
while(true){
    r=(i+1)*2; l=r-1;
    if (*l > * i) { 
       if (*r > *l) swap(i,r);
       else swap(i,l);
    }
    else { 
       if (*r >* i) swap(i,r);
       else break;
    }
 }
```

The swap operation must as a side effect also update the address `i` either to `l` or `r`.
Differing from the textbook solution, we don't check if the addresses of the children are valid, but we trade space to speed allocating a buffer of 32 zeros at the end of the array. Once `i` is not larger than either of the children, the traversal to the bottom of the heap ends.